# Enabling the android "next button" with Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, android-keypad

I have developed with Ionic and AngularJS an app which lets me fill in an HTML form. The app works well. If I install the app on the device and want to fill the form, the "Next Button" will not appear on the Android keyboard.I see just the "Go Button". How can I activate the "Next" button on the Android keyboard, so I can switch from one form field to another with the "Next" button.

Answer (score -1):

Add `cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);` inside  `$ionicPlatform.ready` function like:

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {

      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }

  });
})
```